# Darts database to keep stats

Tags: sql, database

I'm looking to create a web app to keep stats from darts game.

I'm quite stuck in the creation of the database.

[image]

I know it's wrong as I can't recover the leg stats for each player but I don't know how to solve this correctly.

A match has at least two legs, and I need to keep track of stats of each player playing the leg (as number of darts thrown for example).

So, for a game, I need to be able to get the Game played, which player have played the game and the stats of both players.

How can I link those tables to be able to get that ? Did I have to add another table between games and legs maybe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be, what are you looking for:
[image]
Now you can have information about players in every leg. You can insert there information about score. In player table insert information about players. Game table contain information about whole game. For every leg is one row in Game table. Changed DB schema, maybe this is more suitable to you.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that, but the problem is that a game can have several legs (2 or 3).

Comment: But you should think, if this is a problem. In fact, game consists of many legs. You can have either many legs in a game or information about game in every row in Leg table. You can choose, what is more suitable to you.

Comment: I see, but in that case, the foreign key shouldn't be in the Leg table ? But anyway, let's say I have to set how many darts where thrown by each player. So, leg_id = 1, player_1_id = 1, player_2_id = 2, nb_darts = ???

Comment: You could just insert this information in Leg table, leg_id = 1, player_1_id = 1, player_2_id = 2, darts_player_1 = 3, darts_player_2 = 4. If you need, you can have additional table, which is referenced to table Leg, where have you information about every turn of a player. This table could look like this: id = 1, leg_id = 1, player_id = 1, turn = 1, score = 50. It depends, how much details do you need.

Comment: Yeah, I think this one works perfectly :) thank you !

Comment: I am happy that I could help ;)